# Tosafoth's unique opinion that Building is biblically allowed on Yom Tov, contradicted by a simple Gemara in Beitzah?

Tags: yom-tov, maseches-shabbos, lomdus, tosfot, tractate-beitza

Beitzah 9b seems to undermine a famous Tosafoth in Shabbath 95a that introduces a fascinating Hiddush that Boneh (construction) on Yom Tov should be Mutar, but is forbidden because of rabbinic enactment due to its mundane nature.

Beitzah 9b has R' Yehudah reconciling B' Hillel and B' Shammai to agree that it's Asur to carry your roof-repair ladder to do something Mutar on Yom Tov because of Marith 'Ayin*.

If that is the case, then how could Tosafoth come up with the Hiddush in Shabbath 95a?  Isn't it undermined by a plain reading of the Gemara in Beitzah?

<sub>*Though it seems to be widely held now, the idea of applying Marith 'Ayin to Isurei DeRabanan is not at all clear, and it appears as a point of direct Mahloketh between the Sha"Ch and RaM"A in Y"D 87.</sub>

Comment: One possible answer might be that Tosafoth hold that Marith 'Ayin applies even to Issurei DeRabbanan (Sha"Ch Y"D 87:4:8).

Comment: @SethJ s.v. *v'harodeh*: תימה לר"י כיון דמותר לגבן בי"ט מן התורה אפילו באפשר אפילו לא יהא מותר מדרבנן אלא בדלא אפשר אם כן נפל ביתו בי"ט יהא מותר לבנותו בי"ט דמתוך שהותר בנין לצורך דמגבן הוי משום בונה כדאמר בסמוך הותר נמי שלא לצורך ובלבד שיהא צורך היום לאכול בתוכו שלא יכנו שרב ושמש וי"ל דאסור מדרבנן דהוי עובדא דחול כי היכי דאסורין טחינה והרקדה ביו"ט

Comment: @SethJ See Tosafos (*K'suvos* 60a, [s.v. ממעכן](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=60&format=text)), who writes that *mar'is ayin* applies only in public for d'rabbanans, but even in private for d'oraysas. (Incidentally, the citation for the Shach should be 87:6).

Comment: @Fred, kudos. You're absolutely right.  I skimmed 6 and didn't see it, and 8 looked close enough. I get lazy at 2 in the morning.

Comment: @Fred, and thanks for the language of the Tos. I had found it before you posted it, but thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 1):

Tosfos agrees that boneh is assur  min hatorah when it is not for yom tov.

As such, there is a maris ayin to carry a ladder since an observer may very well suspect the ladder carrier of fixing a roof for a non yom tov need.

Comment: So why not for carrying a pot? People may suspect you are cooking for dogs

Comment: Most cooking is for people not dogs. Most ladder carrying is for non heter use. Even fixing one's roof often includes maintenance that is not needed immediately.